Multiplying inner products of inner products
I'm looking at a proof of the Schwarz inequality that starts like the following:
$$ |Z \rangle = |V\rangle - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} | W \rangle \\ \langle Z|Z \rangle = \langle V | V \rangle - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle \langle V|W\rangle}{|W|^2} - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle^*\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} + \frac{\langle W|V\rangle^*\langle W|V\rangle \langle W|W\rangle}{|W|^4} \leq 0$$
At this point, I'm less concerned with the equality of zero part than I am with just trying to understand how to handle the algebra of this expansion. I've tried to follow the distributive and other properties of inner products to fill in the missing steps, but I'm not finding a lot of information on how to handle inner products that contain expressions with other inner products.
Here's what I came up with so far, but I'm sure it's mostly wrong:
$$ \langle Z|Z \rangle = \langle \ \ \ V - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} W \ \  | \ \ V - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} W \ \ \rangle \\$$
$$ = \langle \ V \ | \ V - \frac{\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} W \ \rangle - \langle \ \ \frac{\langle W | V \rangle }{|W|^2}W \ | \ V - \frac{\langle W | V \rangle } {|W|^2} W \ \ \rangle $$
$$ = \langle \ V \ | \ V \ \rangle - \langle V | \frac{\langle W|V\rangle}{|W|^2} W \ \rangle - \langle \ V - \frac{\langle W | V \rangle }{|W|^2}W \ | \ \frac{\langle W | V \rangle } {|W|^2} W \ \ \rangle ^*$$
I realize this isn't complete, but by this point, I doubt the expansion is correct, so I could use some help.
Update:
Thanks to the answer from @dummy, below is a more complete solution.
Let:
$$ a = \frac{\langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2} $$
Then, we have:
$$ \langle Z|Z \rangle = \langle V - a W | V - a W \rangle$$
$$ = \langle V | V \rangle + \langle - a W | V \rangle + \langle V | -aW \rangle + \langle -aW | -aW \rangle$$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle + \langle V | -aW \rangle ^* + (-a) \langle V | W \rangle + (-a) \langle -a W | W \rangle$$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle + (-a)^* \langle V | W \rangle ^* + (-a) \langle V | W \rangle + (-a) \langle W | -aW \rangle ^*$$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle + (-a)^* \langle W | V \rangle + (-a) \langle V | W \rangle + (-a) (-a)^* \langle W | W \rangle ^* $$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle + (-\frac{\langle W | V \rangle^*}{|W|^2}) \langle W | V \rangle + (-\frac{\langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2}) \langle V | W \rangle + (-\frac{\langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2}) (-\frac{\langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2})^* \langle W | W \rangle ^* $$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle - (\frac{\langle V | W \rangle \langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2}) - (\frac{\langle W | V \rangle \langle V | W \rangle}{|W|^2}) + (\frac{\langle W | V \rangle \langle V | W \rangle \langle W | W \rangle}{|W|^4}) $$
$$= \langle V | V \rangle - (\frac{\langle W | V \rangle \langle V | W \rangle}{|W|^2}) - (\frac{\langle V | W \rangle \langle W | V \rangle}{|W|^2}) + (\frac{\langle W | V \rangle \langle V | W \rangle \langle W | W \rangle}{|W|^4}) $$
